# Por qué mi petición sale cancelada? PUT

Tags: javascript, reactjs, xmlhttprequest

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación con react, javascript y flask.
A la hora de hacer dos peticiones PUT seguidas, la primera aparece cancelada en chrome.
Tengo que poner algún tipo de retardo entre ambas peticiones?
No se qué me puede estar fallando.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Es un bucle for donde divido un array de elementos y compruebo cada uno por separado. Si el elemento ya está en mi base de datos, hago un put. Si no está, hago un post.

Al hacer la prueba con 2 elementos que ya están en la base de datos, el primer PUT me aparece cancelado. Ambos elementos tienen los mismos parámetros.

```
function send_data() {
    const Http = new XMLHttpRequest();

for (var i = 0; i < id.length; i++) {
    if (id[i] == 0) {
        console.log("POST "+id[i])
        Http.open("POST", url);
        Http.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");
    }
    else {
        console.log("PUT "+id[i])
        Http.open("PUT", url + "/id/" + id[i]);
        Http.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");
    }
    Http.setRequestHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT');
    Http.setRequestHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    
    
    var new_product = new_values[i];

    Http.send(JSON.stringify({
        "conc_max_agua_n": new_product['Conc max agua N kg/m3'],
        "conc_max_agua_p": new_product['Conc max agua P kg/m3'],
        "consumo_n": new_product['Consumo N.    kg/ha'],
        "consumo_p": new_product['Consumo P     kg/ha'],
        "cultivo": " " +new_product['Cultivo'] ,
        "cultivo_id": new_product['Cultivo'],
        "etc": new_product['Etc'],
        "eto_m3ha": new_product['ETo.  m3/ha'],
        "eto_mm": new_product['Eto mm'],
        "kc": new_product['Kc'],
        "pp_efectiva_año": new_product['Ppefectiva          (mm año)'],
        "pp_efectiva_dia": new_product['Ppefectiva    (mm día)'],
        "precipitacion": new_product['Precipitación anual  (mm)'],
        "produccion": new_product['Produccion     (t/ha)'],
        "riego": new_product['Riego (m3/ha)'],
        "year": parseInt(csv_año['name'])
    })); //393.33
    
}
```

Muchas gracias por cualquier ayuda.

Comment: Cancelada significa que otra peticion posterior en la pagina anulo dicha peticion, por ejemplo un cambio de ubicacion de la pagina (`document.location = '..'` o presionar un link a otra pagina distinta durante la llamada). SI esta accion se desencadena al presionar un link, es probable que debas ajustar esto. Puedes compartir la parte del HTML/javascript que llama a este codigo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo he solucionado finalmente poniendo un retardo entre cada petición de 200ms

```
function sleep(ms) {
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
      }
await sleep(500) //tiempo de espera entre peticiones
```

y especificando que mi función send_data() es asíncrona

```
async function send_data() {
    const Http = new XMLHttpRequest();
    .
    .
    .
}
```